# How to add a class to a li when a child has a particular class

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm a complete beginner so I know this is probably very simple...

I have the following html output for a menu system:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</li>
  <li class="ancestor">
    <a href="#">About</a>   
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Our company</a>       
        </li>
    <li class="selected">
            <a href="#">Our team</a>   
        </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The current page is "Our Team" and so that is flagged as selected.

I would like to be able to add a class to the parent `li` so that I can style it to be highlighted (selected) when we are on the selected page of a child. i.e. So that the `<li class="ancestor">` becomes `<li class="ancestor selected">` or something similar.

The HTML is generated from a CMS so my thoughts are that it would be easiest to use some jQuery to do this.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already? Have you read up on jQuery or done some tutorials to find out how you'd approach this problem?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) here:

```
$('li.selected').closest('.ancestor').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('li.selected').parents('li').addClass('selected');
```

This will add the `selected` class to all `li` elements going upwards, no  matter how many levels.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gm2C6/